# Inserting Selected value from Gridview to Mysql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, ajax

i am working on a project and i have a gridview and a radiobutton in gridview and what i want is,i want to send the selected rows value to database on the click of the button but i am getting an error as object reference not set to the instance of an object.
As my code is 
cs code on the click of the button

```
 protected void btn_selectgridview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int k = 0;
    //Checkther whether atleast one check box is selected or not
    for (int i = 0; i <=gvrepair_details.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gvrepair_details.Rows[i];
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (rb.Checked == true)
        {
            k++;
        }
    }

    if (k == 0)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "<script language=JavaScript>alert('select the value in grid');</script>");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <=gvrepair_details.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        string bookname = gvrepair_details.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
        string categoryname = gvrepair_details.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
        string subcategory =gvrepair_details.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
        string shelf_no = gvrepair_details.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
        string isbn = gvrepair_details.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;
        string edition = gvrepair_details.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text;
        string status = gvrepair_details.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text;
        GridViewRow row = gvrepair_details.Rows[i];
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (rb.Checked == true)
        {
            InsertData(bookname, categoryname, subcategory, shelf_no, isbn, edition, status);
        }
    }

 }
void InsertData(String bookname, String categoryname, String subcategory,String shelf_no,String isbn,String edition,String status)
{
    try
    {
        sql = "insert into library_repair(bookname, categoryname, subcategoryname, shelf_no, isbn, edition, status)values('" +bookname+ "','" +categoryname+ "','" +subcategory+ "','"+shelf_no+"','"+isbn+"','"+edition+"','"+status+"')";
        ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly you get error while debugging?

Comment: if (rb.Checked == true)
        {
            k++;
        }

Comment: If  you try to debug your code, you will find that rb is null. So the problem lies in `(RadioButton)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");`

Comment: After debugging i am getting object reference not set to the instance of an object.at    if (rb.Checked == true) { k++; } –

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (((RadioButton)gvrepair_details.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked == true)
        {
           k++;
        }
```

instead of

```
if (rb.Checked == true)
        {
          k++;
        }
```

Comment: :is any namespace used with this code as it is showing an error on checked (using system.web.ui.control doenot contain any definition for)

Comment: use using System.Web.UI.WebControls

Comment: i have used your namespace updated but still its showing an error

Comment: using.system.ui.webcontrol doenot contain a definition for checked

Comment: .Checked is not coming as you write . after ("CheckBox1"))?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29481/discussion-between-anuj-and-ashish)

Comment: i am still getting the same error after updation of your code  the error is object reference not set to the instance of an object

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I reformulated you first function (Code may contains syntax error since haven't run it):

```
    protected void btn_selectgridview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int k = 0;
        int checkBoxColumnIndex = 2; //Here you should specify the cell containing the checkBox

        foreach (GridViewRow item in gvrepair_details.Rows)
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)item.Cells[checkBoxColumnIndex].FindControl("CheckBox1");

            if (rb != null && rb.Checked) //Check if rb is null
            {
                k++;
                string bookname = item.Cells[1].Text;
                string categoryname = item.Cells[2].Text;
                string subcategory = item.Cells[3].Text;
                string shelf_no = item.Cells[4].Text;
                string isbn = item.Cells[5].Text;
                string edition = item.Cells[6].Text;
                string status = item.Cells[7].Text;

                InsertData(bookname, categoryname, subcategory, shelf_no, isbn, edition, status);
            }
        }

        //Checkther whether atleast one check box is selected or not
        if (k == 0)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "<script language=JavaScript>alert('select the value in grid');</script>");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Note the `checkBoxColumnIndex`. CheckBox1 index should be provided.

Comment: i updated your code but what is happening is when i am not selecting value in gridview popup is showing select the value but when i am selecting the value in grid or making a check on radiobutton still it popup and shows select the value

Comment: @Ashish that is another issue related to when you should popup your message. Maybe you should add more validation for **k**.

Comment: sorie i am not getting u...as i wanna popup when none of the value in gridview is checked

Comment: Maybe because k = 0, which means rb is still null. Check the value of `item.Cells[checkBoxColumnIndex].FindControl("CheckBox1")`

Comment: i am getting rb value as null

Comment: @Ashish Have you set a  value for checkBoxColumnIndex? value should be the column containing the CheckBox